# getting post data with no variables in php

Tags: php, post

if i have a post request that looks like this:

```
POST /page.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
...
...\r\n\r\n
{"name":"json"}
```

notice that post data is sent without a variable name..
is there a way of fetching this?

p.s. tried dumping $_POST, didn't help at all..

Thanks!

Comment: just guessing http_parse_headers() or get_headers()

Answer (score 5):

You can get the POST body via [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

```
$json_object = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
/*
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "json"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried dumping `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`? Because I'll bet that you can find it in there.

---

Note: per the comment, this is no longer the correct behavior with the most recent versions of PHP. You are better off reading the content of `'php://input'` [You can read more about that here.](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: Deprecated soon, should use php://input .
Warning.
This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need content-type header for json interprete:

```
POST /page.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json
...
...\r\n\r\n
{"name":"json"}
```

And now use $_POST['name']